# Sonata Classification Bundle method for getting the products

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

Is there some kind of method hidden in the Classification bundle that gets all the products of the desired category or subcategory?

In my sidebar I am displaying categories and subcategories and I need to show the number of products this subcategory has, but I can find how..

I am easily showing all the needed categories like this. I can even get the number of how many subcategories does the category have... But how to show the number of products?

```
    {% for categories in category %}

        <li class="subMenu" style="cursor:pointer;"><a> {{ categories.name }} [{{ categories.children|length }}]</a>
            <ul>
            {% for subcategory in categories.children %}

                <li><a href="{{ path('products', {id: subcategory.id, name: subcategory.name}) }}">{{ subcategory.getName }}</a>[{{ subcategory.media|length }}]</li>

            {% endfor %}

            </ul>
        </li>

    {% endfor %}
```

In the product.php the categories are mapped like this:

```
/**
 * @var \Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $category;

/**
 * @var \Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subcategory_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $subcategory;
```

But the category.php has nothing in reference to products... How can I get these damn products then?

Comment: Its a uni directional mapping try to define it as a bi directional mapping http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional